# code igniter routing help, 404 issue

Tags: php, routes

Hello i have a codeigniter project that im trying to get off the ground but im having some serious routing issues.

I followed the codeigniter official tutorial to make the news application but i rather have my news pages static then dynamically on a DB.

problem is i want to organize the pages into separate folders

views/pages = for all the sites basic pages
views/news = all the news posts

on my routes.php file i have this

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

i also figured id need a Controller for news so i made this

```
<?php

class News extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home')
{
  if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/news/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

  }
}
```

i also included a home.php file in the news folder to see if it works but everytime i try to reach ziplinegolive.com/index.php/news/ I get a 404 error..

Does anyone have any idea how i can simply do this? I have searched ALOT for solutions but no tutorial is like mine and no one explains it simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I noticed is with your routing:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Your first routing entry here has the same key as your second entry. So, your first entry is wiped out. And, the key `(:any)` will match anything, so your `default_controller` entry (or any other entry which comes after this one) will never be in use.

Also, I believe that in general, CI suggests that you use prettier URLs like 'news/one' instead of something like 'index.php/news/one'. If you wanted to map 'news/one' to the view method of your news controller, your routing entry could look like this:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1'
```

And then your news controller would look something like this

```
class News extends CI_Controller
{
  public function view( $page = 'home' )
  {
    $this->load->view('news/'.$page, $data);
  }
}
```

Lastly, while I strongly recommend against using `file_exists` in the manner you prescribe, the defined constant `APPPATH` is relative, as opposed to an absolute path, which may be causing problems with your `file_exists` call. I would suggest using an absolute path to make sure there are no path resolution issues when checking for file existence

Comment: i have made the first edit you suggested but no luck.... As for editing the controller...

If i copy your code and completely replace it with mine im not seeing how i can reach the home.php file thats in the news folder... ?

Comment: I think you may be confused about how to structure the folders and files in a CI app. Can you post your folder/file structure here?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `load->view` call to make things more clear. That example should now work for the 'news/home` endpoint, given your current file structure. If you can get this simple example working, you can work back on your other issues.

Comment: ok progress! but still some flukes... http://ziplinegolive.com/index.php/news/home when i go to that address i can see the page and the templates load but a huge error displays above it.... also if i point too http://ziplinegolive.com/index.php/news/ it doesnt redirect to the home.php file. Did i do something wrong? i copied your whole steps :/

Comment: Never mind this will work just fine considering I'll have a news.php view in my pages folder

Comment: im having one more issue actually... now i noticed when i go into my news/ directory my template links get all messed up because the news/ directory gets added to the url... any suggestions?